# Consider a number var x="22." So when i convert into float i'm getting it as 22. but i wanted it to be as 22

Tags: javascript

In javascript, i'm trying to use parseFloat on string. My string is "22." so when i'm parsing it to float it is converting to 22 
so is there any flexibility where i can get the float value as 22.

i want it in float. I searched and got a function `"tofixed()"` where i can get it as 22.0 but i want it as 22.

```
var x="22.";
var y = parseFloat(x);
print y // prints 22
```

But i want it to be 22.

I want it with a "." appended in the end

tried using `parseFloat()`

I expect the output of parseFloat to be 22, but the actual output is 22

Comment: `22.` doesn't make sense, how do intend to use the number? If integers are fine then you could use `parseInt`

Comment: where do you need this number? you could add a final markeup for the number, but then you get a string.

Comment: consider i'm developing a calculator where i'm getting the string from keyboard and i'm parsing and displaying it on console so when user clicks on . then i'm not able to see that becaz parsFloat doesn't allow me to

Answer (score 4):

Note that JavaScript does not distinguish between integers and floats.  Both (e.g.) `22` and `22.5` are of type `number`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures.

So if you want the output to look a certain way when printed to the console, it's probably best to manually convert it into a string you're happy with.

Exactly what to do depends on things like what kind of behavior you want when there is a non-integer component to the number.  To get started, maybe try something like:

```
var x = 22;
console.log(x.toFixed(1));
// Prints 22.0
```

It has an extra "0" versus your desired output above, but you could always remove that.

Comment: Furthermore, the OP is confusing the actual value of the variable and its human-readable representation.